# Convert Text into Voice and then this voice make mobile ringtone

Tags: android

I want to store voice into SD-card.
I make an app which convert text into voice by using 
[TextToSpeech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) Class. when text convert into speech, how can i make this voice my mobile ringtone?
Please Help guys :) thanks In advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick example of text to speech conversion:

```
package com.androidhive.texttospeech;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AndroidTextToSpeechActivity extends Activity implements
        TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private Button btnSpeak;
    private EditText txtText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

        btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

        // button on click event
        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                speakOut();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
                speakOut();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }

    private void speakOut() {

        String text = txtText.getText().toString();

        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

You can change the language to speak by using `setLanguage()` function. Lots of languages are supported like Canada, French, Chinese, Germany etc.,

Change pitch rate using `tts.setPitch(0.6);`

[Full reference could be found here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/).

**File rendering and playback**
While the `speakOut()` method is used to make Android speak the text right away, there are cases where you would want the result of the synthesis to be recorded in an audio file instead. This would be the case if, for instance, there is text your application will speak often; you could avoid the synthesis CPU-overhead by rendering only once to a file, and then playing back that audio file whenever needed. Just like for speak(), you can use an optional utterance identifier to be notified on the completion of the synthesis to the file:

```
HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap();
String wakeUpText = "Are you up yet?";
String destFileName = "/sdcard/myAppCache/wakeUp.wav";
myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, wakeUpText);
tts.synthesizeToFile(wakeUpText, myHashRender, destFileName);
```

Once you are notified of the synthesis completion, you can play the output file just like any other audio resource with `android.media.MediaPlayer`.

[Reference for storing the speech in an audio file is here.](http://android-developers.blogspot.fi/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html)

Comment: Thanks Arman :) i did this already .. but i want to make this voice my mobile ringtone .... voice which we get from speakout() function..

Comment: I have edited my answer and added the code for storing the generated speech into audio file in the above answer. Check out the link as well.

Comment: it is not working in android pie depricated how to resolve it cant find anything pls hlep me here